# Error: Write After End pdfkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

For the First Time It Generate Pdf file at server side But when to try to create another it show an error of write after end in server side.

```
pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./dist/files/tmpPdfFile/' + randomName + '.pdf'));

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
});

// Pipe generated PDF into response
pdf.pipe(res);

pdf.addPage();

var count = 0

// if(imagesArr.length>0){
imagesArr.forEach(function (image) {
    if (imagesArr.indexOf(image) === 0) {
        pdf.fontSize(16).fillColor("darkgray")
        pdf.text('ACCIDENT IMAGES', 10, 10, {
            bold: true,
            align: 'center'
        });
    }
    if (count < 2) {
        if (count < 1) {
            pdf.image(image.body, 30, 40, {
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });
            pdf.fontSize(9).fillColor('black');
            pdf.text('Image Type: ' + image.imgType + ' Date: image.dateTime  Time: image.dateTime  Address: image.dateTime', 30, 342);
        } else {
            pdf.image(image.body, 30, 360, {
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });
            pdf.fontSize(9).fillColor('black');
            pdf.text('Image Type: ' + image.imgType + ' Date: image.dateTime  Time: image.dateTime  Address: image.dateTime', 30, 660);
        }
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0
        pdf.addPage();
    }

    if (imagesArr.indexOf(image) === imagesArr.length - 1) {

        pdf.end();
        // window.open(pdf.dataURI());
        stream.on('finish', function () {
            // blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf')

            // or get a blob URL for display in the browser
            // window.open('output.pdf'); 
        })
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @SuhailGupta error shows "write after end" at server side and that's why pdf file not generated

Comment: Please post the complete error trace.

Comment: Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:159:12)
    at PDFReference.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:204:5)
    at PDFPage.write (/home/shubham/vcsClaim/vcs/node_modules/pdfkit/js/page.js:95:27)
    at PDFDocument.addContent (/home/shubham/vcsClaim/vcs/node_modules/pdfkit/js/document.js:161:17)
    at PDFDocument.module.exports.rect (/home/shubham/vcsClaim/vcs/node_modules/pdfkit/js/mixins/vector.js:82:19)
    at Request._callback